# Can;t define and use protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, prototype

I am trying to migrate some Objective-C code to my Swift code but there are some protocol errors in Swift. In my Objective-C all works perfectly.

I have one class say MGCDayPlannerEKViewController,

```
public class MGCDayPlannerEKViewController : MGCDayPlannerViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    public var calendar: NSCalendar!
    public var visibleCalendars: Set<NSObject>!
    public var eventStore: EKEventStore! { get }
    weak public var delegate: MGCDayPlannerEKViewControllerDelegate!

    /** designated initializer */
    public init!(eventStore: EKEventStore!)
    public func reloadEvents()
}

public protocol MGCDayPlannerEKViewControllerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    optional public func dayPlannerEKEViewController(vc: MGCDayPlannerEKViewController!, willPresentEventViewController eventViewController: EKEventViewController!)
    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    optional public func dayPlannerEKViewController(vc: MGCDayPlannerEKViewController!, navigationControllerForPresentingEventViewController eventViewController: EKEventViewController!) -> UINavigationController!
}
```

In my Swift class, I am inheriting this class and also creating one protocol inside my new class

```
protocol WeekViewControllerDelegate :MGCDayPlannerEKViewControllerDelegate,CalendarViewControllerDelegate,UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

}
class WeekViewController: MGCDayPlannerEKViewController {

    var delegate: WeekViewControllerDelegate?
    var showDimmedTimeRanges = false
    var isiPad : Bool {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting error here in delegate declaration. The error is

```
Property 'delegate' with type 'WeekViewControllerDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'MGCDayPlannerEKViewControllerDelegate!' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<MGCDayPlannerEKViewControllerDelegate>')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that in your parent class there is a property with the same name as in it's child. In your code `WeekViewController` and `MGCDayPlannerEKViewController` have a property called `delegate`. You need to rename variable `delegate` in class `MGCDayPlannerEKViewController` or in `WeekViewController`.